# Cloning not happening between two xa datasources of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, jtds, xa, teiid

I am trying to clone data(copy data from one database to another using) using Teiid (jtds 1.3.1 driver) from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2012 (2 XA Datasources), but somehow it is giving me this error.

```
2020-04-03 09:28:28,702 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/ IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@53bb9a24[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@20f311ff connection handles=0 lastReturned=1585886308356 lastValidated=1585886207493 lastCheckedOut=1585886308702 trackByTx=true pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@2602a9fa mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@16ee19d[pool=DSSQLSERVER20200403092646617] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@6ed5e4b8[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@20f311ff pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=Microsoft SQL Server productVersion=11.00.2100 jndiName=java:/DSSQLSERVER20200403092646617] txSync=TransactionSynchronization@128579284{tx=Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a83801:1d1953d1:5e86b22e:4e status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider) wasTrackByTx=true enlisted=false cancel=false}]: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: XAER_INVAL: Invalid arguments were given.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.XASupport.raiseXAException(XASupport.java:707)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.XASupport.xa_start(XASupport.java:198)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsXAResource.start(JtdsXAResource.java:105)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.start(XAManagedConnection.java:259)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.start(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:215)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:741)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:423)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.enlistResource(LocalTransaction.java:157)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:986)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:379)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:554)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:970)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:792)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCExecutionFactory.getConnection(JDBCExecutionFactory.java:278)
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCExecutionFactory.getConnection(JDBCExecutionFactory.java:68)
        at org.teiid.translator.ExecutionFactory.getConnection(ExecutionFactory.java:201)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorWorkItem.execute(ConnectorWorkItem.java:353)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorManager$1.invoke(ConnectorManager.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.getResults(DataTierTupleSource.java:302)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.nextTuple(DataTierTupleSource.java:138)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.AccessNode.nextBatchDirect(AccessNode.java:401)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalNode.nextBatch(RelationalNode.java:277)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalPlan.nextBatch(RelationalPlan.java:141)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatchDirect(QueryProcessor.java:148)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatch(QueryProcessor.java:111)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:160)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:142)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.processMore(RequestWorkItem.java:492)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.process(RequestWorkItem.java:362)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.AbstractWorkItem.run(AbstractWorkItem.java:47)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.run(RequestWorkItem.java:285)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DQPWorkContext.runInContext(DQPWorkContext.java:277)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$RunnableWrapper.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:115)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$3.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,717 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/ ARJUNA016089: TransactionImple.enlistResource - xa_start  - caught: XAException.XAER_INVAL for < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffffc0a83801:1d1953d1:5e86b22e:4e, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffc0a83801:1d1953d1:5e86b22e:57, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:/DSSQLSERVER20200403092542311 >: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: XAER_INVAL: Invalid arguments were given.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.XASupport.raiseXAException(XASupport.java:707)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.XASupport.xa_start(XASupport.java:198)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsXAResource.start(JtdsXAResource.java:105)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.start(XAManagedConnection.java:259)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.start(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:215)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:741)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:423)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.enlistResource(LocalTransaction.java:157)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:986)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:379)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:554)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:970)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:792)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCExecutionFactory.getConnection(JDBCExecutionFactory.java:278)
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCExecutionFactory.getConnection(JDBCExecutionFactory.java:68)
        at org.teiid.translator.ExecutionFactory.getConnection(ExecutionFactory.java:201)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorWorkItem.execute(ConnectorWorkItem.java:353)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorManager$1.invoke(ConnectorManager.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.getResults(DataTierTupleSource.java:302)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.nextTuple(DataTierTupleSource.java:138)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.AccessNode.nextBatchDirect(AccessNode.java:401)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalNode.nextBatch(RelationalNode.java:277)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalPlan.nextBatch(RelationalPlan.java:141)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatchDirect(QueryProcessor.java:148)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatch(QueryProcessor.java:111)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:160)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:142)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.processMore(RequestWorkItem.java:492)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.process(RequestWorkItem.java:362)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.AbstractWorkItem.run(AbstractWorkItem.java:47)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.run(RequestWorkItem.java:285)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DQPWorkContext.runInContext(DQPWorkContext.java:277)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$RunnableWrapper.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:115)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$3.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/ javax.transaction.xa.XAException: XAER_INVAL: Invalid arguments were given.
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.XASupport.raiseXAException(XASupport.java:707)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.XASupport.xa_start(XASupport.java:198)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsXAResource.start(JtdsXAResource.java:105)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.start(XAManagedConnection.java:259)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.start(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:215)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:741)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:423)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.enlistResource(LocalTransaction.java:157)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:986)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:379)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:554)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:970)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:792)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCExecutionFactory.getConnection(JDBCExecutionFactory.java:278)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCExecutionFactory.getConnection(JDBCExecutionFactory.java:68)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.translator.ExecutionFactory.getConnection(ExecutionFactory.java:201)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorWorkItem.execute(ConnectorWorkItem.java:353)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorManager$1.invoke(ConnectorManager.java:229)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.execute(Unknown Source)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.getResults(DataTierTupleSource.java:302)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.nextTuple(DataTierTupleSource.java:138)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.AccessNode.nextBatchDirect(AccessNode.java:401)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalNode.nextBatch(RelationalNode.java:277)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalPlan.nextBatch(RelationalPlan.java:141)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatchDirect(QueryProcessor.java:148)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatch(QueryProcessor.java:111)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:160)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:142)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.processMore(RequestWorkItem.java:492)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.process(RequestWorkItem.java:362)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.AbstractWorkItem.run(AbstractWorkItem.java:47)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.run(RequestWorkItem.java:285)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DQPWorkContext.runInContext(DQPWorkContext.java:277)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,731 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$RunnableWrapper.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:115)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,747 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$3.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:206)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,747 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,747 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,747 ERROR [stderr] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    
    2020-04-03 09:28:28,747 WARN  [org.teiid.CONNECTOR] (Worker3_QueryProcessorQueue62) xXEXRoF5iMN/ Connector worker process failed for atomic-request=xXEXRoF5iMN/.4.0.4: org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCExecutionException: 0 TEIID11013:TEIID11004 Error executing statement(s): [Prepared Values: [1] SQL: INSERT INTO "XXXXXX"."dbo"."test1" ("id") VALUES (?)]
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCUpdateExecution.executeTranslatedCommand(JDBCUpdateExecution.java:345)
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCUpdateExecution.execute(JDBCUpdateExecution.java:82)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorWorkItem$1.execute(ConnectorWorkItem.java:433)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorWorkItem.execute(ConnectorWorkItem.java:392)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorManager$1.invoke(ConnectorManager.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.getResults(DataTierTupleSource.java:302)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.nextTuple(DataTierTupleSource.java:138)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.AccessNode.nextBatchDirect(AccessNode.java:401)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalNode.nextBatch(RelationalNode.java:277)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalPlan.nextBatch(RelationalPlan.java:141)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatchDirect(QueryProcessor.java:148)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatch(QueryProcessor.java:111)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:160)
        at org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:142)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.processMore(RequestWorkItem.java:492)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.process(RequestWorkItem.java:362)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.AbstractWorkItem.run(AbstractWorkItem.java:47)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.run(RequestWorkItem.java:285)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DQPWorkContext.runInContext(DQPWorkContext.java:277)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$RunnableWrapper.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:115)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$3.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:245)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:1928)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:1943)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransaction(WrappedConnection.java:1917)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:447)
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCBaseExecution.getPreparedStatement(JDBCBaseExecution.java:192)
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCUpdateExecution.executeTranslatedCommand(JDBCUpdateExecution.java:249)
        ... 28 more
```

My datasource configurations are as listed below:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/DSSQLSERVER20200403092542311" pool-name="DSSQLSERVER20200403092542311">
    <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
        testsonali1
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
        1433
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
        10.20.26.67
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Instance">
        SQL2012
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
    <xa-pool>
        <min-pool-size>4</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>XXXXX</user-name>
        <password>XXXXXX</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
</xa-datasource>
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/DSSQLSERVER20200403092646617" pool-name="DSSQLSERVER20200403092646617">
    <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
        testsonali
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
        XXXX
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
        XXXXXX
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Instance">
        XXXXXX
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
    <xa-pool>
         <min-pool-size>4</min-pool-size>
         <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
         <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>XXXXXX</user-name>
        <password>XXXXXXX</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
         <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
         <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
         <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
</xa-datasource>
```

And my driver configurations are as listed below:

```
<driver name="sqlserver" module="net.sourceforge.jtds">
     <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
     <xa-datasource-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

Please help me with the resolution. Thanks in advance!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Microsoft JDBC Driver for this, as there are few issues with XA JOIN found with JTDS driver.

Comment: HI Ramesh, I have tried using Microsoft's JDBC driver but it is taking much longer time to deploy vdb for larger schemas ,as compared to JTDS.

Comment: The SQL SERVER JDBC driver version I have used is "mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8"

Comment: I do not have any performance metrics, one solution for long load times is to have the metadata imported in the model if you are using deploy time download of the metadata (dynamic vdb), then it will skip that task and deployment will be much faster.

Comment: Hi Sir, our scenario is that we are testing whether the connection to a database can be made via teiid, so in that can we perform the solution which you mentioned above?

Comment: Also can you give some reference as to how to do it?. We are using AdminClient Apis to deploy the vdb

Comment: How did you design your VDB? using the Teiid Designer or XML/DDL file?

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, I added import properties of table and schema names while fetching metadata and it is working faster.